# Replace all image "<a href" url, with the picture url from "<img src"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

i use wordpress and i have a rss posting issue. some image for linking having the external post url and if a user clicks they open the external website.

I try to replace with php all image links with the img source but without luck.

in example i have a post with 2 images:

```
"blah blah blah"
<a href="http://google.com/thank-you.html"><img src="http://yahoo.com/img/top.jpg" alt="" /></a>
"blah blah blah"
<a href="http://google.com/index.html"><img src="http://yahoo.com/img/bottom.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

I wanna to transform this into this:

```
"blah blah blah"
<a href="http://yahoo.com/img/top.jpg"><img src="http://yahoo.com/img/top.jpg" alt="" /></a>
"blah blah blah"
<a href="http://yahoo.com/img/bottom.jpg"><img src="http://yahoo.com/img/bottom.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Also replace img linking one by one with php.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe better for [wordpress.se]?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
    jQuery('.img').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).parent('a').attr('href', this.src);
    });
```

html

```
    <img class="img" src="http://yahoo.com/img/top.jpg" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<script>
var getSrc = function(imgSource) {
var img = new Image();
img.src = imgSource;
return img.src;
};
$( "a" ).attr({
href: getSrc,
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

html

```
<a href="http://google.com/thank-you.html"><img class="image" src="http://yahoo.com/img/top.jpg" alt="dsfds" /></a>
<a href="http://google.com/index.html"><img class="image" src="http://yahoo.com/img/bottom.jpg" alt="ad" /></a>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.image').each(function(){
    var src = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    jQuery(this).parent('a').attr('href', src);
});
```